# Magento block reference order

Tags: magento, reference, block

I created a custom extension on Magento to render a block on the main content. But how do I choose the order be displayed? Right now is being displayed below the content.
Is there a way to define after or before a block? How do I get see the name of the blocks to render before or after?

```
    app/code/local/SpaceName/Infrontpage/Block/Infrontpage.php
    <?php 
 class Rand_Infrontpage_Block_Infrontpage extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{

    function getcustombanner() {


        return 'FERNANDAO CUSTOM BLOCK';

        }
 }

?>
```

> Then I have:

```
app/code/local/SpaceName/Infrontpage/etc/config.xm<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
         <Rand_Infrontpage>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Rand_Infrontpage>
    </modules>
    <global>   
        <blocks>
            <infrontpage>
                <class>Rand_Infrontpage_Block</class>
            </infrontpage>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <infrontpage>
                    <file>infrontpage.xml</file>
                </infrontpage>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> and:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/infopage.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">

    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
             <block type="infrontpage/infrontpage" name="infrontpage" template="infrontpage/infrontpage.phtml" />
        </reference>

    </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

> and finally:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/infrontpage/infrontpage.phtml\
<h1 class="infrontpage" style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $this->getcustombanner(); ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento the `before="child.block.name"` and `after="child.block.name"` attributes are used to define the order of blocks. If those attributes are not specified then the blocks will render in the order that Magento reads them.

for example

```
<reference name="root">
   <block type="core/template" name="example_block" before="content" template="page/html/example-block.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. How do i get the name of the block so I can create a hook before it?